# What prevents a node from receiving a solved solution and claiming it as its own work?

Tags: nodes

During the relay process a node finds the solution and forwards that solved block to all other nodes in the network to validate that it has indeed solved the problem. But then what if another node decides to rebroadcast it again and claim that he was the one who found the answer first.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do you modify the block or do you not modify the block?

If you don't modify the block, it still pays the mining reward to the same account. So you've just done what everyone wants you to do.

If you do modify the block, it won't be valid anymore until and unless you mine it. That leaves you two choices:

1) You can ignore this block and mine some other block. But then someone else who mines on top of this block will have a longer chain than you and you won't get any reward. So why would you do this?

2) You can mine on top of this block. Well, that will just help ensure the person who mined that block gets their reward by producing an even longer chain that includes their block.

Comment: A block contains: Version, HashPrevBlock, HashMerkelRoot, Time, Bit, Nonce, which one of these is the miner identifier.

Comment: @UtsavMitrakaushiBasak None of those are. The coinbase transaction specifies what account the mining reward is paid to. The HashMerkleRoot is the hash of the Merkle tree of transactions, including the coinbase transaction. The whole point of mining is to secure the transactions.

Comment: Understood, as in the transaction for the reward is included in the block, so no matter who confirms it the reward will go to the sender right?

Comment: @UtsavMitrakaushiBasak Everyone confirms the same block. The whole point of mining is to bind the transactions into the block so that they cannot be disassociated. There is nothing but the block. There isn't a block plus something else that claims it somehow. The block is the claim.

Comment: I still don't get it. When the solution is broadcasted, I don't have to modify a block. I simply use the nounce thats broadcasted, abandon the block in which the solution was broadcasted and creaty my own with the solution I just stole and then broadcast my new blockchain to as many nodes as possible and simply hope I'm connected to more than the original sender. I still see a big problem here.

Comment: You say "create your own with the solution I just stole". That is impossible. If you create your own block, you will have no solution to the block you just created. A solution for one block is of no use when trying to produce a different block (otherwise, you could just re-use the solution to an old block!). If you abandon the block, you abandon the solution to that block.

Comment: So, the coinbase transaction in the block that I'm about to mine changes the puzzle I want to solve, and thus, the correct answer to it? (The other transaction and data are of no value to me, they can stay the same)

Comment: @user2762996 Yes. The puzzle is to find a valid next block. The block is the solved puzzle.